# How can one make a wiki page in a personal space editable by someone other than the owner of the personal space in Atlassian Confluence?

Tags: permissions, wiki, confluence

I created a page in my personal space Atlassian Confluence and gave edit access to someone:

[image]

I can see the edit option on my side:

[image]

but the other person can't.

In the personal space permission, only view/add/delete can be set, not edit:

[image]

How can one make a wiki page in a personal space editable by someone other than the owner of the personal space in Atlassian Confluence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Re-How-can-one-make-a-wiki-page-in-a-personal-space-edit/qaq-p/2087609/comment-id/249160#M249160) by [Rilwan Ahmed](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/716861):

> Go to your `space --> Space Tools--> permissions`.
>
> See what groups and individual users are added to All(View) and Pages Add permissions.
> If the required user is added in these permissions, then then user will have access to edit the pages unless restricted from page level restrictions.
>
> [image]